# how to avoid hardcoded calls and attain same results on divs with same classname

Tags: jquery

this is in html file.

```
<div class="pageNavPosition"></div>
<table></table>
<div class="pageNavPosition"></div>
<script>
showPageNave('pager','pageNavPosition');
</script>
```

this code in js file.

```
    this.showPageNav = function(pagerName, divname) {
    var pagerHtml = ['<a href="#" class="prev" onclick="' + pagerName + '.prev();"> &lt Prev </a> '];
    for (var page = 1; page <= this.pages; page++){
          pagerHtml.push('<a href="#" class="'+ page +'"onclick="' + pagerName + '.showPage(' + page + ');">' + page + '</a>  '); 
    }
    pagerHtml.push('<a href="#" class="next" onclick="'+pagerName+'.next();"> Next &gt;</a>');                  
    $("."+divname).append(pagerHtml.join(""));     
    if(this.pages > 9){
          $(".pageNavPosition a:lt(" + this.endMask + "):gt("+this.buffer+")") .css("display","none").hide();                                
          $('<a class="dotline" >.....</a>').insertAfter($(".pageNavPosition a:eq(" + Math.ceil(this.pages/2) + ")"));                                                           
     }                                       
}
```

what i wanted to do is 1,2,.....,9,10 both at the top and bottom of the table. This working fine for div above table but not the div at the bottom.i tried using `$("."+divname` instead of (hardcoded)`$(".pageNavPosition` , and with .each() but i was not successful. any ideas are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it in a jsfiddle:
http://www.jsfiddle.net/jeXBh/

it works in both divs for me.
(I also simplified the code a bit. I think it's better to create the dots in the loop already instead of changing the html afterwards.)

Comment: in this case if am not wrong the pages within the range of 4-8 will not be added at all..this might hinder me from showing them later as am implementing front end pagination.

Comment: Andy am trying to use push instead of append(suggested for better performance) but wasn't successful if at all you get a chance ..please enlighten me of my errors you can find my code here http://jsfiddle.net/stack/YbKaa/4/

Comment: Hi, you could add the style directly to the link for example: http://jsfiddle.net/YbKaa/5/

Answer (score 0):

May be you've to close the div tag?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".page").html("My html code");
  });
```

```
<div class="page"> </div>
   <div class="MyContent">
bla bla bla
 </div>
   <div class="page"> </div>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){}  is not mandatory, simply put the js after the divs, as you allready done.

Answer (score 0):

each should work for you.... but I think your may be getting some scoping issues, try:

```
if(this.pages > 9){
    var that = this;
    $("." + divname).each(function() {
        var initial = $(this).find("a:eq(" + Math.ceil(that.pages/2) + ")");
        $(this).find("a:lt(" + that.endMask + "):gt("+that.buffer+")")
            .hide();
        $('<a class="dotline" >.....</a>')
            .insertAfter(initial); 
    });
 }
```

in any case, this approach seems to me a bit convoluted, you may try an approach like the one andy mentions...

Comment: $("."+divname).append(pagerHtml.join("")); is working fine even if i dont use .each() real problem for me is at $(".pageNavPosition a:lt("+this.endMask+"):gt("+this.buffer+")") .css("display","none").hide();                                
 $('<a class="dotline" >.....</a>').insertAfter($(".pageNavPosition a:eq("+Math.ceil(this.pages/2)+")"));

Comment: output am having right now is like                                   1,2,3...9.10,Next                                                   [table containing results ]                                  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,Next

Comment: sorry for the confusion, check the edit, it now shows the same set of links in both divs